# Get order id in a custom payment method: Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am working on a new payment method for shop and I am stuck in the method can refund. In this function I would need to find a way to get the order id of the invoice to refund. How should I proceed?

```
  class Company_Module_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
  {
    (...)
    public function canRefund() // we need a way to get the orderId
    {
      $client = $this->_getCLient();
      $client->loadOrder($orderId); // <------ here I would need the order id or increment id
      $ret = $client->canRefund();
      return $ret;
    }
    (...)
  }
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$paymentInfo = $this->getInfoInstance();
$orderId = $paymentInfo->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
```